# Can I load non-module libraries into webpack module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I want to load non-module libraries into webpack module. The non-module libraries don't have module.exports method. Is there any way to achieve it?

My example library being on **http://localhost:8080/exampleLib/exampleLib.js** url.

Here is my library,

```
// exampleLib.js

function example(){
   console.log('from example library');
}
```

I want to load my exampleLib from webpack and compile that into module and set my lib to global. Can I do it?

```
// expetation in webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    externals: {
         exampleLib: 'http://localhost:8080/exampleLib/exampleLib.js'
    }

}
```

If that's possible, Is there any way to add non-module as chunks?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to shim, you can read the documentation on shimming a module in the wiki: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules

Comment: If you add the example of shimming, I can easy to understand shimming. Can you please do it?

Answer (score 0):

Tim Elsass's answer is right: shimming is the right concept to go for here. There is now a Webpack [Shimming Guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/). In particular, [`exports-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/exports-loader/) can be used to load a JS file that doesn't export anything. I unfortunately don't understand "externals" well so I don't think I can provide an example that will solve the exact problem.